# Complete shopify backup offline

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

I have created shopify site now i want to create backup system for it.
I want to know is there is any way to create backup of each and everything daily basic on my local computer by default. Actually i don't want to depend on plugins

Answer (score 0):

You can create a private App for yourself in your shop. With those credentials you are free to use the Shopify API to download all the assets of your shop to your local computer. Consider that a backup. Note that you cannot as of yet download your navigation links, but that is pretty much the only thing you cannot backup.

You will find this to be a challenge, backing up your site.

Comment: this is good suggestion but how to create shopify app do you know any framework with whom i can do it easily

Comment: i got one solution skyvia but its doing backup on cloud

Comment: rewind.io is another solution. There is nothing easy for you. Either you learn Shopify inside out to backup your site, or you pay.